# Is there a way to prevent Google App Engine datastore viewer from cutting off text objects?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am running Java GAE SDK 1.7.2. This is the datastore viewer on localhost.

Also, is it possible to not have returns (\n) removed from the text, so that I can see them in datastore viewer?

Look at the second row input - that is where the text is cut off.
[image]

Comment: it is what it is. You are probably better off writing your own interface to your data so you can see it exactly how you want to. There is a place you can put feature requests for future versions, I don't have a link to hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Paul C's tip was not very good. Instead of creating your own interface, the easiest thing to do is to try and use Greasemonkey or something to alter the page.